# How to install tailwindcss in android?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, termux

I want to install Tailwind CSS on Android, but when I want to install it an error appears saying that access is denied, and isn't the file data/data/com.termux out of access and how can I solve this other than rooting?

I have tried using acodeX, but it failed, and I used another folder that I can access but still doesn't have permission

Answer (score 0):

You can first give permission of storage and then try again.
Using:

```bash
termux-setup-storage
```

Or You can use this cli method to use tailwindcss using termux(or AcodeX)

1. Install nodejs

```bash
pkg install nodejs
```

2. Start a node project

```bash
mkdir my-project && npm init
```

3. And follow the official tailwind guide

`https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation`